# Migrate from Opensuse to Ubuntu

Tags: migration

I have been tasked by my job to upgrade their opensuse environment to ubuntu. I am a novice level linux user (ive only really played/studied with ubuntu) and I honestly dont even know where to start. Ive done some google searches and read the migration document on one of the ubuntu sites but it does not give much information on HOW to do this. I was hoping someone can give me a sort of play by play on how to do this or at least point me in the right direction. Is it as simple as copying over all the files to their respective folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am not an expert of this sort of thing, so take this with a grain of salt.)

You might try using the Live CD to see if you can do what you want with the OpenSuse partition in Ubuntu, and if everything works like you want it to you can do a manual installation with the same CD to leave the OpenSuse partition intact. You can get the ISO to burn to the CD from http://www.ubuntu.com/download.

If it were me I would install Ubuntu fresh and move files from OpenSuse over to Ubuntu, but that is only because I do not understand partitioning well enough.

Definitely give the Live CD a try though. You will probably be surprised what you can do with it.

Comment: Wonder how you got that job ! Maybe you mean something different . That is really very little experience to work as an sysadm. Good luck anyway..